# Geodesic expansion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

I have some questions regarding the geodesic expansion:

1. Is the expansion of ingoing congruences always required to be negative?
2. For both ingoing and outgoing geodesics, is $\frac{d\Theta}{d\lambda}$ required to be always negative?

Comment: Define $\Theta$ and $\lambda$. Does this have anything to do with a black hole?

Comment: $\Theta$ is the expansion of null geodesic congruences and $\lambda$ is an affine parameter along the geodesic.

Comment: You need to expand your question more. It isn't very clear what you have in mind. What do you mean by ingoing and outgoing? Are you looking at a spacelike two surface? We have to guess many things. Under the assumptions that I have guessed you are interested in the answer to both questions is 'No'.